# Object is Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I'm created on delegate class to call methods.But is crash some time calling `EXC_BAD-ACCESS` .

Here is [image: snap] :

I also checked whether object is or not :

```
if(_chatDelegate == (id)[NSNull null] || !_chatDelegate)
    Glb.ChatWithUer  = jidString;
else
  [_chatDelegate newBuddyOnline:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", roomName]  roomJID:jidString];
```

How to check if this getting crashed ?

Comment: check, chatDelegate respondsToSelector(newBuddyOnline:roomJID) and then proceed

Comment: @M. K. sorry but it crash same ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(_chatDelegate == (id)[NSNull null] || !_chatDelegate)
    Glb.ChatWithUer  = jidString;
else if(_chatDelegate)
    [_chatDelegate newBuddyOnline:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",roomName]  roomJID:jidString];
```

Since in the debugger it looks like the delegate is null so we check if there is a delegate before calling it.

Comment: You have to trigger the method to see if it does crash or not, posting some code source may help.